# Unable to post using React Form to backend running on nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

xhr.js:220  POST http://localhost:5000/posts 404 (Not Found)

posts.js:21 Request failed with status code 404

Comment: Did you check that the listener is listening for a post request?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this with Postman before posting with React application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your nodeJS server, your endpoint is not working "http://localhost:5000/post"